# mysql query based on ticket status

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm working on a ticketing system where analysts will be assigned tickets based on a specific criteria.

When they first log in they will click on the Get Net Ticket button.

The tickets are assigned as follows:

1. First: Open (oldest ticket with status of Open)
2. Second:Pending (any tickets with Pending status when pend date =
   today)
3. Third: Ready (oldest, new (unassigned) ticket)

So if they click Get Next it will look for oldest open, if none > select Pending today, if none > select oldest Ready.

Below is my query but it doesnt seem to be working reliably. Any suggestions?

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM support_case
    WHERE (
    case_status = 'Pending'
    AND case_queue = 'Software'
    AND pendDate = '12/15/2011')
    OR (
    case_status = 'Open'
    AND case_queue = 'Software')
    OR (
    case_status = 'Ready'
    AND case_queue = 'Software')
    ORDER BY lastUpdate ASC 
    LIMIT 0 , 1
```

Comment: What do you mean with `not reliably`? The query does not follow your 'first-second-third' business rule? How should it, with the `ORDER BY lastUpdate ASC`?

Answer (score 1):

This will sort them by support_case, then by oldest open.

Open will be sorted oldest->newest, followed by Pending sorted oldest->newest, then Ready sorted oldest->newest.

```
SELECT * 
FROM support_case
WHERE ( 
case_status = 'Pending' 
OR case_status = 'Open' 
OR case_status = 'Ready' )
AND case_queue = 'Software'
ORDER BY support_case ASC, lastUpdate ASC
LIMIT 1
```

If you had different status values (that weren't nicely alphabetical), you could restructure your database, or add a new column, to give a numerical value to your case_status.  Then you can add an `ORDER BY case_status_value DESC` to your query.

So:
'Open' = 10
'Pending' = 5
'Ready' = 1

So that Open are returned first, then pending, then ready.  Then you can query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM support_case
WHERE ( 
case_status = 'Pending' 
OR case_status = 'Open' 
OR case_status = 'Ready' )
AND case_queue = 'Software'
ORDER BY case_status_value DESC,
lastUpdate ASC
LIMIT 1
```

See @konerak's comments below for another option that accomplishes the same, without the column structure changes.

Comment: Adding a value could work. But here, you can also ORDER ON the `case_status`, since in this specific case, it appears the desired order equals the alphabetic order :)

Comment: @Konerak Nice, I guess I need to learn my alphabet... here I thought Pending was going to throw it for a loop ;)

Comment: Feel free to add that into your answer - and your 'add a value solution' would be the more generic case. There is a shortcut, still: instead of adding a column, one could just `ORDER BY CASE case_status WHEN 'Open' THEN 3 WHEN 'Pending' THEN 2 WHEN 'Ready' THEN 1`. Saves adding a column, but moves the logic to the query. Each approach has advantages.

Comment: I did not know about CASE logic. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the feedback...only thing missing is that if a case is open or ready it wont have a pend date. ie: if we do a get next, the first in the order of operations is "Pending". If a case has a pending status, we check to see if the pending date = today. if the pending date is <> today we go to the next criteria - Open (no pending date - just status and queue). If no tickets are "Open", we move to "Ready", etc.